# Dropbox like application

Tags: backup, dropbox

Does anyone know of a application which can be downloaded and run our your own servers which contains a web interface which can be used to access data you have backed up to it using either rsync for FTP etc using different login accounts?

Comment: sparkleshare will be the app you want. if/as/when its ready

Comment: Or VMWare's project Octopus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://sparkleshare.org/ this is what you are looking for